# What does the future package mean when it says mcapply is known to be unstable?

Tags: r, future

I'm trying to understand the quote below from the future package.  What is meant by "known to be unstable"?  Does that mean it mcapply might crash, or are the result from mcapply not reliable?

"Parallelization via multi-threaded processing (done in native code by some packages and external libraries) while at the same time using forked (aka "multicore") parallel processing is known to unstable. Note that this is not only true when using plan(multicore) but also when using, for instance, mclapply() of the parallel package."

Answer (score 0):

For stability, use one of layer of multi-processing or multi-threading at a time.  So if you call mcmapply, run version of functions inside the mcmapply call that do not themselves use multiple processes or threads.  That being said, I have had more stability problems with future than mcmapply. The problem is that I cannot run small tests on Windows before deploying to Ubuntu.